# Qt Quick 2.0 in Windows XP

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I installed Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.7, 823 MB)

Then I created simple Quick 2 application and compiled it. Program runs on clean Windows 7, Windows 8. But program does not run on Windows XP. And I have this error:

**Точка входа в процедуру _vsnprintf_s не найдена в библиотеке DLL msvcrt.dll**

Translate: **The procedure entry point _vsnprintf_s not found in library DLL msvcrt.dll**

Error

What to do? Where and what libraries to take the program to run?

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar bug in the [list of known issues.](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt501KnownIssues)

Try to use MSVC2010 compiler.